# Jquery: Handling Checkbox Click Event with JQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I can't figure out what is going on here.  I have some nested lists of checkboxes that I would like to check when the parent is checked.  More importantly, I can't even get the alert to show up.  It's as if the click event is not firing.  Any ideas?

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#part_mapper_list input[type=checkbox]").click(function(){
    alert("clicked");
    if ($(this).attr("checked") == "checked"){
        $(this + " input").attr("checked") = "checked";
    } else {
        $(this + " input").attr("checked") = "";
    }
});
}
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<div>
<ul id="part_mapper_list">
<?php
$makes = array("Audi", "BMW", "Mini", "Porsche", "Volkswagen");
$generations = array("Generation 1", "Generation 2", "Generation 3", "Generation 4", "Generation 5");
$modelclusters = array("Model Cluster 1", "Model Cluster 2", "Model Cluster 3", "Model Cluster 4", "Model Cluster 5");
$cars = array("Car 1", "Car 2", "Car 3", "Car 4", "Car 5");

    foreach($makes as $mappermake){
        echo "<li id=\"" . $mappermake . "\" class=\"mapper_make\">+<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"mapper_make\" value=\"" . $mappermake . "\">" . $mappermake . "</input><ul>";
        foreach($generations as $mappergen){
            echo "<li id=\"" . $mappergen . "\" class=\"mapper_gen\">+<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"mapper_gen\" value=\"" . $mappergen . "\">" . $mappergen . "</input><ul>";
            foreach($modelclusters as $mappermodelcluster){
                echo "<li id=\"" . $mappermodelcluster . "\" class=\"mapper_modelcluster\">+<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"mapper_modelcluster\" value=\"" . $mappermodelcluster . "\">" . $mappermodelcluster . "</input><ul>";
                foreach($cars as $mappercar){
                    echo "<li id=\"" . $mappercar . "\" class=\"mapper_car\"><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"mapper_car\" value=\"" . $mappercar . "\">" . $mappercar . "</input></li>";
                }
                echo "</ul></li>";
            }
            echo "</ul></li>";
        }
        echo "</ul></li>";
    }
?>
<input id="submit_mapping" type="submit">
</div>
```

Comment: Please share your HTML because at the very least you should receive the alert with the code shown.

Comment: can you provide the aproper html markup?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're missing a closing bracket ) at the end of your code sample. Is that a copy and paste error or is that the case in your code?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#part_mapper_list input[type=checkbox]").click(function(){
    alert("clicked");
    if ($(this).attr("checked") == "checked"){
      $(this + " input").attr("checked") = "checked";
    } else {
      $(this + " input").attr("checked") = "";
    }
  });
});
```

**Edit for below comment:**
I'm not entirely sure if I understand what you're trying to do, but try this *untested* code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#part_mapper_list input[type=checkbox]").click(function() {
    $("#" + $(this).val() + " input[type=checkbox]").attr("checked", $(this).attr("checked"));
  });
});
```

Comment: Ah that fixed the alert, but the nested checkboxes are not responding to the parent checkbox.

Comment: I like the way you think!  So simple, why didnt I think of that!?!?! :-D

Comment: There's always a simpler way to do anything! I can think of a way to simplify that code further (hint: $.find()), but I'm much too lazy. Also, if you ever have any problems like the alert not showing, then that usually means you've missed a bracket, or another minor syntax error. Firebug (firefox extension) and JSLint (JS code-checking website) will be good first-stops for syntax errors. Happy coding!

Answer (score 3):

If the alert isn't firing there might problem with our HTML markup, please verify it is well-formed and that you properly nested tags.

I would be much helpful if you can as well post your HTML code, for us to inspect the problem.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#part_mapper_list :checkbox").click(function(){
    alert("clicked");
    if (this.checked){
        //$(this + " input").attr("checked") = "checked";
    } else {
        //$(this + " input").attr("checked") = "";
    }
  });
});
```

if the markup are correct and valid, directly access the checked propery of the rawdom object instead of wrapping it with jquery to  minimize overhead.

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#part_mapper_list :checkbox").click(function(){
     $(this).find(":checkbox").attr("checked", this.checked);
  });
)};
```

Answer (score 0):

**try this** 
*check multiple checkboxes with jquery

check all check boxes with single click

on click for multiple checkbox

select all checkbox with onclick event

select all check box with single checkbox select*
HTML CODE

```
<div class="field-type-list-boolean field-name-field-select-all field-widget-options-onoff form-wrapper" id="edit-field-select-all"><div class="form-item form-type-checkbox form-item-field-select-all-und">
 <input type="checkbox" id="edit-field-select-all-und" name="field_select_all[und]" value="1" class="form-checkbox">  <label class="option" for="edit-field-select-all-und">Select All </label>

</div>
</div>
<div class="field-type-list-boolean field-name-field-select-none field-widget-options-onoff form-wrapper" id="edit-field-select-none"><div class="form-item form-type-checkbox form-item-field-select-none-und">
 <input type="checkbox" id="edit-field-select-none-und" name="field_select_none[und]" value="1" class="form-checkbox">  <label class="option" for="edit-field-select-none-und">Select None </label>

</div>
</div>

<div id="edit-field-culture-und" class="form-checkboxes"><table class="multicolumncheckboxesradios-table"><tbody><tr class="odd"><td class="multicolumncheckboxesradios-column-first multicolumncheckboxesradios-column">&nbsp;</td><td class="multicolumncheckboxesradios-column"><div class="form-item form-type-checkbox form-item-field-culture-und-4">
 <input type="checkbox" id="edit-field-culture-und-4" name="field_culture[und][4]" value="4" class="form-checkbox">  <label class="option" for="edit-field-culture-und-4">Austria </label>

</div>
</td><td class="multicolumncheckboxesradios-column"><div class="form-item form-type-checkbox form-item-field-culture-und-7">
 <input type="checkbox" id="edit-field-culture-und-7" name="field_culture[und][7]" value="7" class="form-checkbox">  <label class="option" for="edit-field-culture-und-7">Croatia </label>

</div>
</td><td class="multicolumncheckboxesradios-column"><div class="form-item form-type-checkbox form-item-field-culture-und-13">
 <input type="checkbox" id="edit-field-culture-und-13" name="field_culture[und][13]" value="13" class="form-checkbox">  <label class="option" for="edit-field-culture-und-13">Finland (English) </label>

</div>
</td><td class="multicolumncheckboxesradios-column"><div class="form-item form-type-checkbox form-item-field-culture-und-17">
 <input type="checkbox" id="edit-field-culture-und-17" name="field_culture[und][17]" value="17" class="form-checkbox">  <label class="option" for="edit-field-culture-und-17">Hungary </label>

</div>
</td><td class="multicolumncheckboxesradios-column"><div class="form-item form-type-checkbox form-item-field-culture-und-16">
 <input type="checkbox" id="edit-field-culture-und-16" name="field_culture[und][16]" value="16" class="form-checkbox">  <label class="option" for="edit-field-culture-und-16">Latvia </label>

</div>
</td><td class="multicolumncheckboxesradios-column"><div class="form-item form-type-checkbox form-item-field-culture-und-20">
 <input type="checkbox" id="edit-field-culture-und-20" name="field_culture[und][20]" value="20" class="form-checkbox">  <label class="option" for="edit-field-culture-und-20">Norway (Norwegian) </label>

</div>
</td><td class="multicolumncheckboxesradios-column"><div class="form-item form-type-checkbox form-item-field-culture-und-23">
 <input type="checkbox" id="edit-field-culture-und-23" name="field_culture[und][23]" value="23" class="form-checkbox">  <label class="option" for="edit-field-culture-und-23">Slovakia (English) </label>

</div>
</td><td class="multicolumncheckboxesradios-column multicolumncheckboxesradios-column-last"><div class="form-item form-type-checkbox form-item-field-culture-und-24">
 <input type="checkbox" id="edit-field-culture-und-24" name="field_culture[und][24]" value="24" class="form-checkbox">  <label class="option" for="edit-field-culture-und-24">Sweden (Swedish) </label>

</div>
</td></tr><tr class="even"><td class="multicolumncheckboxesradios-column-first multicolumncheckboxesradios-column">&nbsp;</td><td class="multicolumncheckboxesradios-column"><div class="form-item form-type-checkbox form-item-field-culture-und-6">
 <input type="checkbox" id="edit-field-culture-und-6" name="field_culture[und][6]" value="6" class="form-checkbox">  <label class="option" for="edit-field-culture-und-6">Belgium (Dutch) </label>

</div>
</td><td class="multicolumncheckboxesradios-column"><div class="form-item form-type-checkbox form-item-field-culture-und-8">
 <input type="checkbox" id="edit-field-culture-und-8" name="field_culture[und][8]" value="8" class="form-checkbox">  <label class="option" for="edit-field-culture-und-8">Czech Republic </label>

</div>
</td><td class="multicolumncheckboxesradios-column"><div class="form-item form-type-checkbox form-item-field-culture-und-14">
 <input type="checkbox" id="edit-field-culture-und-14" name="field_culture[und][14]" value="14" class="form-checkbox">  <label class="option" for="edit-field-culture-und-14">France </label>

</div>
</td><td class="multicolumncheckboxesradios-column"><div class="form-item form-type-checkbox form-item-field-culture-und-3">
 <input type="checkbox" id="edit-field-culture-und-3" name="field_culture[und][3]" value="3" class="form-checkbox">  <label class="option" for="edit-field-culture-und-3">Ireland </label>

</div>
</td><td class="multicolumncheckboxesradios-column"><div class="form-item form-type-checkbox form-item-field-culture-und-18">
 <input type="checkbox" id="edit-field-culture-und-18" name="field_culture[und][18]" value="18" class="form-checkbox">  <label class="option" for="edit-field-culture-und-18">Malta </label>

</div>
</td><td class="multicolumncheckboxesradios-column"><div class="form-item form-type-checkbox form-item-field-culture-und-21">
 <input type="checkbox" id="edit-field-culture-und-21" name="field_culture[und][21]" value="21" class="form-checkbox">  <label class="option" for="edit-field-culture-und-21">Poland (Polish) </label>

</div>
</td><td class="multicolumncheckboxesradios-column"><div class="form-item form-type-checkbox form-item-field-culture-und-11">
 <input type="checkbox" id="edit-field-culture-und-11" name="field_culture[und][11]" value="11" class="form-checkbox">  <label class="option" for="edit-field-culture-und-11">Spain (Catalan) </label>

</div>
</td><td class="multicolumncheckboxesradios-column multicolumncheckboxesradios-column-last"><div class="form-item form-type-checkbox form-item-field-culture-und-25">
 <input type="checkbox" id="edit-field-culture-und-25" name="field_culture[und][25]" value="25" class="form-checkbox">  <label class="option" for="edit-field-culture-und-25">United Kingdom </label>

</div>
</td></tr><tr class="odd"><td class="multicolumncheckboxesradios-column-first multicolumncheckboxesradios-column">&nbsp;</td><td class="multicolumncheckboxesradios-column"><div class="form-item form-type-checkbox form-item-field-culture-und-5">
 <input type="checkbox" id="edit-field-culture-und-5" name="field_culture[und][5]" value="5" class="form-checkbox">  <label class="option" for="edit-field-culture-und-5">Belgium (French) </label>

</div>
</td><td class="multicolumncheckboxesradios-column"><div class="form-item form-type-checkbox form-item-field-culture-und-9">
 <input type="checkbox" id="edit-field-culture-und-9" name="field_culture[und][9]" value="9" class="form-checkbox">  <label class="option" for="edit-field-culture-und-9">Denmark </label>

</div>
</td><td class="multicolumncheckboxesradios-column"><div class="form-item form-type-checkbox form-item-field-culture-und-10">
 <input type="checkbox" id="edit-field-culture-und-10" name="field_culture[und][10]" value="10" class="form-checkbox">  <label class="option" for="edit-field-culture-und-10">German </label>

</div>
</td><td class="multicolumncheckboxesradios-column"><div class="form-item form-type-checkbox form-item-field-culture-und-15">
 <input type="checkbox" id="edit-field-culture-und-15" name="field_culture[und][15]" value="15" class="form-checkbox">  <label class="option" for="edit-field-culture-und-15">Italy </label>

</div>
</td><td class="multicolumncheckboxesradios-column"><div class="form-item form-type-checkbox form-item-field-culture-und-19">
 <input type="checkbox" id="edit-field-culture-und-19" name="field_culture[und][19]" value="19" class="form-checkbox">  <label class="option" for="edit-field-culture-und-19">Netherlands (Dutch) </label>

</div>
</td><td class="multicolumncheckboxesradios-column"><div class="form-item form-type-checkbox form-item-field-culture-und-22">
 <input type="checkbox" id="edit-field-culture-und-22" name="field_culture[und][22]" value="22" class="form-checkbox">  <label class="option" for="edit-field-culture-und-22">Portugal </label>

</div>
</td><td class="multicolumncheckboxesradios-column"><div class="form-item form-type-checkbox form-item-field-culture-und-12">
 <input type="checkbox" id="edit-field-culture-und-12" name="field_culture[und][12]" value="12" class="form-checkbox">  <label class="option" for="edit-field-culture-und-12">Spain (Spanish) </label>

</div>
</td><td class="multicolumncheckboxesradios-column multicolumncheckboxesradios-column-last">&nbsp;</td></tr></tbody></table></div>
```

THEN JQUERY CODE

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://caarcher.biz/ryn/ryn/misc/jquery.js?v=1.4.4"></script>
<script language="javascript1.1" >
(function ($){

        $(document).ready(function(){
                    alert("this is text");

                        $("[id^='edit-field-select']").click(function(){
                            alert("found anoather one");
                            if($("#edit-field-select-all-und").is(":checked") )
                                {

                                    $("#edit-field-select-none-und").attr("disabled",true);
                                    $("#edit-field-select-none-und").attr("checked",false);
                                    $("[id^='edit-field-culture-und-']").attr("checked",true);
                                    $("[id^='edit-field-culture-und-']").attr("disabled",true);

                                }else if($("#edit-field-select-none-und").is(":checked"))
                                {
                                    $("#edit-field-select-all-und").attr("disabled",true);
                                    $("[id^='edit-field-culture-und-']").attr("checked",false);
                                    $("[id^='edit-field-culture-und-']").attr("disabled",true);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    $("[id^='edit-field-select']").attr("disabled",false);
                                    $("[id^='edit-field-culture-und-']").attr("checked",false);
                                    $("[id^='edit-field-culture-und-']").attr("disabled",false);
                                }
                        });




            });
}) (jQuery);
</script>
```